# Reason for new user's reputation is set to 1

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

Why new user's reputation is set to 1 not 0? Any specific reason? 0 is not a negative number at all.

Comment: 1 is psychologically (and mathematically) far more positive than 0.

Comment: Also, pretty sure the down-votes are people disagreeing with you that 0 is just as good as 1.

Comment: @Felix Yes, that'd be a rather fitting duplicate.

Comment: For the record, this one has -7 while the dupe has +22 because this one asking to change the existing behavior to start with 0,  the other one just asked why. People here don't agree with that request to change initial reputation to 0.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd : my intention was just to know if any specific reason is there. I wasn't asking for change in current system. sorry for bad english. And regarding the duplicate, my question was for new comer, not downvoting. Thanks

Comment: "New user can start with 0 reputation". To me it sounds like expressing an opinion. As for duplicate, more accurate to say that other question got answer that fits here in your case as well. To quote Jeff: *A rep of zero or negative seemed cruel. Plus, everyone starts out as "a one" instead of "a zero"*

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 5):

As a recently joined user, I assumed that the 1 reputation point was a token of good faith from Stack Exchange. Just a tiny symbol to show that S.E. believe that people are likely to be more good than bad (or neutral) in general.

Comment: As a new joined user you get +1 from me