# Why is a suspended user's rep set to 1?

Tags: support, reputation, account-suspension

I don't mean "why is it 1, not 0" as in [Reason for new user's reputation is set to 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174710/reason-for-new-users-reputation-is-set-to-1) which was closed as a dupe of [Why does reputation start at 1, and have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1). I mean why is it changed at all?

I understand that lowering the rep is an easy way to prevent certain actions - commenting, voting, chatting, flagging and presumably many more - but it doesn't prevent all of them. You don't need any rep to ask, to answer, to comment on your own question, or to comment on answers to your own question. Presumably code is in place to check whether users are suspended and keep them from doing these things. So why does the rep go to 1?

A side effect is that it screams "this user is suspended" to people who would otherwise not have noticed. I got some rep on an ancient answer today, +30 in all, and noticed on my second visit to the question (trying to figure out what was causing the interest in it) that the person with the other answer on the question had a rep of 1 even though the score of the answer was higher than it had been on my earlier visit.

I clicked through to the profile, and sure enough the user is suspended to cool down. I have no idea why and what for, because I haven't seen any other activity from that user. In such a circumstance, it feels odd for me to even become aware of the suspension. I'm not saying remove that information from the profile, I understand why it is there, but I am curious about the big waving LOOK AT ME flag that a reputation of 1 represents.

Is there a technical reason for it? Did it make coding some of the suspension stuff easier? Or is it in fact supposed to be a nudge-wink to others who happen to read the user's questions or answers? Is it supposed to sting a little, like a scarlet letter of some kind? I am genuinely asking why it is done, not saying that it shouldn't be or quibbling about 1 vs some other number.

Comment: Agree it's weird and probably unique to Stack Exchange. All other sites with users (cough, forums) I know of, are showing "banned/suspended" instead. Pretty sure it was answered before though.

Comment: I [now understand why it's familiar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91627/152859). lol.