# Still 1 rep despite no longer being suspended

Tags: bug, reputation, account-suspension, reputation-recalc, caching

After serving a one month suspension, I am now able to post questions and answers but little else.

As can be seen in the screenshot below, I only have 1 rep. My badges and the number of edits are visible, but rep is stuck at 1. I think this is a bug.... well, I hope so. It seems weird that everything else is in order except for that statistic.

> [image: profile page showing earned badges and number of posts edited with 1 reputation point]

Should I worry? Is this a problem of caching? I searched *[cache rep suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=cache%20rep%20suspended)* but none of the four posts were relevant. I also searched *[is:answer cache reputation 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20cache%20reputation%201)* but none of the 19 results seem to share the same problem.

This is not a duplicate of [Why is a suspended user's rep set to 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229095/why-is-a-suspended-users-rep-set-to-1) as I am *not* suspended now.

Comment: It takes some time that the engine recalculates your rep. When exactly did your suspension end?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think my suspension ended about 30 minutes ago, maybe a little more. Not sure. As this appears to have never happened before, I could be wrong, I think I'll leave my post up.

Comment: Last time a suspension ended for me it took about 1h to recalculate the rep.

Comment: Welcome back :)

Comment: Your rep is back now. Youshouldblamecaching.com

Comment: @Luuklag It's not really _caching_ for that case.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile thank you, it's back to the grind. Let's see how long this stint will last :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Welcome back. I've enjoyed reading your previous posts, finding them quite well written and thought-provoking. I look forward to reading your future posts.

Comment: I'm so glad your suspension is over.  Did I misunderstand something -- I thought it was for one year, which I was pretty upset about.  Did you appeal?  If so, did that involve a "contact us" missive, with an actual *answer from a human being*?  (I've pretty much given up on using "contact us" at this point.) // If you wanted to nominate yourself for a moderatorship somewhere (hypothetically), do you think the rule about no suspensions anywhere disallowing it would still hold in the current exceptional climate?

Comment: It was and has always been one month, @aparente, the last suspension from Meta was for a month.